# dimension not matching for a nd array

Tags: python

I have created an nd array from a file as:

```
for i in range(int(atoms)):
    next(finp)
    for j in range(int(ldata[2])):
        aatom[i][j] = [float(x) for x in
                       finp.readline().strip().split()]
```

Which I am expecting to be a 3d array(`i,j,x`). But its not. After converting it to a numpy array as:

```
atom = np.array(aatom)
print(atom.shape)
```

yeilds: `(250, 301)` which is the dimension of `i,j`. But, in my think process, it is indeed 3d as:

```
print(atom[1][1][:])
```

yeilds: 
`[-3.995, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]`

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: My guess is the lists in each `aatom` cell have different lengths and NumPy creates a `object` array (an array of `list`s instead of `float`s). Can you show some of the raw `aatom` array and `atom.dtype`? Also you should be using `atom[0, 0, :]` instead of `atom[0][0][:]`.

Comment: Have a look at the numpy.loadtxt method. It reads data from a text file into a 2d array. You can probably reshape the result into the 3d array you want.

Comment: Hi Nils, your guess is absolutely correct. Corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: Great! Please remember to mark my answer (added one below) as correct once the option becomes available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nested lists are probably of different lengths, forcing NumPy to create an array of `dtype=object`, meaning an array of `list`s instead of `float`s.

compare

```
a = [range(3), range(2)]  # different lenghts in inner lists
aa = np.array(a)
print aa
print aa.shape            # (2,)
print aa.dtype            # dtype('O')
```

and

```
b = [range(3), range(3)]  # equal lenghts in inner lists
bb = np.array(b)
print bb
print bb.shape            # (2, 3)
print bb.dtype            # dtype('int64')
```